# Android Jellybean stock browser in Samsung S3 is rendering SVG improperly

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, samsung, 4.3-jelly-bean, stock-browser

I have been using SVG to render images in my App, the images render improperly in Samsung S3 device's NATIVE BROWSER only. They work fine in CHROME browser in the same device. What could be the reasons for this anomaly? The App is built upon Sencha Touch (Ext.js) framework and all UI is tended by the Sencha. Also this issue seems to creep in certain images only. Some images appear fine while others don't. Additionally, images that aren't rendered properly in potrait orientation, appear fine in landscape orientation and vice versa. I have attached screenshots for reference.

Thanks.

[image: SVG Image in Potrait]

[image: SVG Image in Landscape]

Answer (score 0):

This is probably NOT an Android issue, but would be true for any device with a smaller view port. See the [SVG Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html) about things that would limit the field of view. Most likely a combination of transform, viewbox, and canvas.

If you believe these are correctly stated in your code, some other combination will maybe serve better. If not stated at all, you risk the app to make approximate guesses during rendering.